# Python 3 int and string conversions

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, selenium, int

I have a couple of questions. Just to explain what is going on in this code, I am taking the subscriber count of a youtube channel and trying to convert it to an int so that it can be multiplied, divided, etc.

Is there a way to put in something like ". followed by any three characters" in the .replace method. This is because some youtube channels have something like "3.04M" subscribers. When I extract that string from the HTML, I want to be able to turn it into an int. That is the first "if" statement, I am trying to say " if the sub count has a decimal followed by 3 characters ie; two numbers and the letter, then remove the decimal and replace the letters with the corresponding amount of zeros, according to the placement of the decimal. If there are NOT 3 characters after, I want to go to the first "else" which only lowers the value of the letters by a factor of 10, not 100 because of the decimal placement. Lastly, if there are no decimals, I simply want to convert the letters into the regular amount fo zeros.

I should probably point out that I am extremely new to python, only about 3 days working with it. Prior experience was like 10 hours of java that I have all but forgotten.

Thanks for any help that could be offered!

```
subC = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/div[3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/app-header-layout/div/app-header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/yt-formatted-string')
print('subscriber count is: ' + str(subC.text))

if ".XXX" in subC.text:
    subC.text.replace('k' , '0')
    subC.text.replace('M' , '0000')
    subC.tect.replace('B' , '0000000')
else:
    if "." in subC.text:
        subC.text.replace('k' , '00')
        subC.text.replace('M' , '00000')
        subC.text.replace('B' , '00000000')
        subC.text.replace('.' , '')
    else:
        subC.text.replace('k' , '000')
        subC.text.replace('M' , '000000')
        subC.text.replace('B' , '000000000')

(realSub, other) = subC.text.split(maxsplit=1)

print(int(realSub))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex and dictionaries you can achieve what you're looking for:

```
import re
d = {'M': 1000000, 'k': 1000, 'B': 1000000000}
subC = ['3.04M', '5M', '3.4k']
for sub in subC:
    if re.search('([a-zA-z])', sub ):
        match = re.search('([a-zA-z])', sub ).group(1) #Get the M
        subC2 = float(sub .replace(match,'')) # Remove the M and turn it into a float

        sub_number = int(subC2*d.get(match)) # Use dictionary to convert it to millions
    else:
        sub_number = int(subC)
    print(sub_number)
```

Maybe I missed one of your cases, please let me know if that happened or if you didn't understand something. This will work *only* if your string is the sub count, if that's not the case, some modifications might me needed.

### Output:

```
3040000
5000000
3400
```

Comment: I think your solution might not work if there are not 2 numbers after the decimal point or if there is no decimal point at all (i.e. 3.4k or 5M).

Comment: @TobiasNöthlich, it's true. I simplified it so it works in those scenarios, but that assumes the string is just the sub count and nothing more

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
realsub = subC.text
realsub.casefold()
if realsub[-1].isalpha():
    last = realsub[-1]
    num = 1000 if last=='k' else 1000000 if last=='m' else 1000000000
    realsub = int(float(realsub[:-1])*num)
print(realsub)
```

The `casefold` converts the string to lowercase. If the last character is alphabet the number is multiplied by the required integer `num`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do that. If I understood correctly, the numbers can come in these formats (with k, M or B):

- 3.04M
- 3.4M
- 3M

To match the ".XXX" format of the first case you can use

```
import re

if bool(re.search('\.[0-9][0-9].', subC)):
    subC = subC.text.replace('.','') 
    subC = subC.text.replace('k' , '0')
    subC = subC.text.replace('M' , '0000')
    subC = subC.text.replace('B' , '0000000')
else:
    if "." in subC.text:
        subC = subC.text.replace('k' , '00')
        subC = subC.text.replace('M' , '00000')
        subC = subC.text.replace('B' , '00000000')
        subC = subC.text.replace('.' , '')
    else:
        subC = subC.text.replace('k' , '000')
        subC = subC.text.replace('M' , '000000')
        subC = subC.text.replace('B' , '000000000')
subC = int(subC)
```

Notice that you need to explicitly assign the string where you replaced something to your original variable, as it does not get saved automatically.
As a little extra, the regular expression works as follows:

- "\." matches the .
- "[0-9]" matches any number from 0-9
- "." matches any character